# Ingesting Large Oracle Table Into Databricks takes longer

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, bigdata, databricks

I have an oracle table containing 50 Million Records and about 13-15 columns and having composite primary key. I am trying to fetch this table into databricks using *oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver*. I have tried two different approaches as below:

**Approach 1**

```
val myDF = spark.read.jdbc(url = url,
table = "TableName",
columnName="PartionColumn",
lowerBound=lowerBound,
upperBound=UpperBound,
numPartitions=10,
connectionProperties)

myDF.write.option("mergeSchema", "true").format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("TableName")
```

**Approach 2**

```
val myDF = spark.read.jdbc(url, query, connectionProperties)

myDF.write.option("mergeSchema", "true").format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("TableName")
```

And this takes more than 25 hours.

Also, when I try to load data into dataframe and display it, it doesn't display the result.

Can someone suggest me what I am doing wrong here ? Or any help on best approach to achieve this would be appreciated.